# Geometry Proof - Similarity

Tags: geometry

1. a) Imagine placing a tetrahedron down on a table flat. Now imagine taking horizontal cross sections of the tetrahedron.  Each cross-section is a triangle.

Show that the area $B(h)$ of the cross-section at height h above the table is given by

$$B(h) = (1 − \dfrac{h}{H})^2. \quad       0≤ h ≤ H$$

---

1. $B$ and $B(h)$ are similar triangles
2. Therefore, $B$ and $B(h)$ must be proportional
   $\implies B(h) = kB$, with $k$ being the area ratio.
   That is, $k$= Area ratio = (Scale factor)$^2$.

When $h = 0, B(h) = B$, and when $h=H, B(h)=0$.
Therefore, $0≤ h ≤ H$.

Now, $\dfrac{h}{H} ≤ 1$, therefore scale factor = $(1- \dfrac{h}{H})$
So $K = (1-\dfrac{h}{H})^2$ and $B(h) =(1-\dfrac{h}{H})^2$. $A, 0≤ h ≤ H$

---

c) Generalise your result to the case where the base is not a triangle but a flat polygon with 4 or more edges.

**Had no idea to where to start with this. I have a feeling I'd have to split the triangle but yea. I'm lost on this.**

Answer (score 0):

All the horizontal slides are similar figures and therefore each of their areas is also given by A(h).

To find the volume, you are integrating the same expression (with a difference constant A).

That is all.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by the difference constant A. are you talking bout the constant we get when just integrate a function?, as in  [integral of A(h)] + A?

Comment: @limteh 'A' is essentially the area of the base. Of course, different shapes have different areas. However, for a particular object, its base area is fixed and therefore is a constant (wrt its corresponding horizontal slides).

Answer (score 0):

Please give different labels for clarity. $ A$ for lengths, $B$ for areas.

The scale factor or ratio for *any* polygon side length as well as height is $A= (1-\frac{h}{H})$. For the area it is $ A^2 =  B = (1- \frac{h}{H})^2$ by applying your own method of similarity of sides and areas.